# Speeding Ticket Fine Calulation

Tags: python

This program calculates the speeding ticket costs

The policy is that every ticket is $50 plus $5 for each mph over the limit, plus a penalty of $200 for any speed over 90 mph. However, if a speed is not 5 mph over the speed limit, that ticket can be waived. (e.g. if a speed limit is 37, you may drive at 41 but not at 42.) The  program asks the user how many tickets they have, and for each ticket asks for the speed limit & clocked speed. I want to calculate and print the fine for each ticket and return the sum total of all the fines and Report a fine of $0 for a ticket if the clocked speed was not over the limit or if the ticket can be waived.

This is my code which works fine for single ticket i want help for doing this for many tickets i am new to python.

```
def ask_limit():
    limit = float(input ("What was the speed limit? "))

    return limit
def ask_speed():
    speed = float(input ("What was your clocked speed? "))
    return speed
def findfine(speed, limit):
    if speed > 90:
        bigfine = ((speed - limit) * 5 + 250)
        print "your fine is", bigfine
    elif speed <= limit:
        print "you were traveling a legal speed"
    else:
        fine = ((speed - limit) * 5 + 50)
        print "your fine is", fine

def main():
    limit = ask_limit()
    speed = ask_speed()
    findfine(speed, limit)
main()
```

Comment: Looks a lot like homework. Are you expected to take all of the speeds and limits from a file? Or from querying the user over and over again?

Comment: No its not homework i am learning python. I want to ask the user for how many tickets he want at the start of the program.

Comment: Not from file by querying the user over and over again.

Comment: This algorithm doesn't include the larcenous NYS fine that is charged if you receive two or more citations within 6 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to repeat something, consider using either a `while` or `for` loop. A `while` loop is for when you want to continuously repeat until some condition is `True`, and a `for` loop is for when you want to do something a set number of times. For example:

```
def main():
    done = False
    while not done:
        limit = ask_limit()
        speed = ask_speed()
        findfine(speed, limit)

        done = raw_input("Done? ") == "yes"
```

Notice I used another `raw_input` to make sure the user can stop the program.

Keep in mind that the limit and the speed is not remembered each time. As the program currently stands, it cannot return the sum total of the tickets. I'll leave it as an exercise to you to figure out the best way of doing so.

Comment: I followed your answer and made changes to my code.
http://ideone.com/PdZRx7
Can you please tell me what is wrong with my new code

Comment: @VineetJain - You need to call the `main` function at the bottom of the file. You also need to add the line `totalfine = 0` before the while loop, otherwise Python won't know what `totalfine` is set to at the first loop. The `ask_tickets` function shouldn't be placed inside the `while` loop, otherwise it'll constantly be repeated over and over. If you want to specify the number of tickets the user must use, consider using a `for` loop, rather then a `while` loop.

Comment: @VineetJain - The corrected code might look like [this](http://pastebin.com/q4KYEt7f). The only changes I made were to `ask_tickets`, `main`, and to the bottom of the file.

Comment: Thank you Michael0x2a it is perfect. I am just wondering if i can make the same program using only if/then/for/loops statements.

Comment: @VineetJain - What do you mean? Isn't it doing that already? Or do you mean you want to write your program so it doesn't use functions? I guess you could, but it would make your code messier, and would be a step backwards.

Comment: When i run this program with this input it shows the following error can you please check it again

Enter the number of tickets  3
What was the speed limit?  40
What was your clocked speed?  30
you were traveling a legal speed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 38, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 33, in main
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'